# nested loops from classic asp to asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, webforms

```
<%
    sql ="select distinct QF_ID,description from vwwQF_Avg_4 where teacher_id ="&Teacher_Id &" order by qf_id"
    ObjRs1.Open SQL, dbDSN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    Count=1
    While not ObjRs1.EOF
    '************************************************ Main Loop for Performa Questions ********************************
    qf_id=ObjRs1("qf_id")
    %>
    <tr>
    <td align=center><%=Count%></td>
    <td align=left class="fd1"><%=ObjRs1("description")%></td>
    <%
    sql ="select * from vwwQF_Avg_4 where teacher_id ="&Teacher_Id &" and qf_id = "&qf_id&" order by offered_course_id"
    'response.write sql & "<br>"
    ObjRs2.Open SQL, dbDSN, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
    While not ObjRs2.EOF
    '******************************************** Inner Loop for Average in Each Selected course ************************
    %>
    <td align=center><%=round(ObjRs2("average"),2)%></td>
    <%
    ObjRs2.movenext
    wend
    %>
    </tr>
```

I need to convert this type of code from classic asp to web forms in asp.net ,

This code iterates over multiple recordsets, one record set value given to another query and another record set is appended in html, there are many like this, in whole page, how to best translate in asp.net webforms.

Comment: Learn to use data bound controls in ASP.NET, especially Repeater, DataList, DataGrid, GridView.

Comment: They are nested so can it be better to simply build the HTML code in a StringBuilder, and put the result in a Literal control.

Comment: You can use a Repeater with nested Repeaters, and use the ItemDataBound event to populate the next Repeater.